# How to append data to all the leaf nodes of a clojure map?

Tags: data-structures, clojure

I have a map data structure in clojure:

**{:category_id 1, :name "ELECTRONICS", :lft 1, :rgt 20, :children [{:category_id 6, :name "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS", :lft 10, :rgt 19, :children [{:children [{:rgt 13, :lft 12, :name "FLASH", :category_id 8}], :category_id 7, :name "MP3 PLAYERS", :lft 11, :rgt 14} {:rgt 18, :lft 17, :name "2 WAY RADIOS", :category_id 10} {:rgt 16, :lft 15, :name "CD PLAYERS", :category_id 9}]} {:children [{:rgt 6, :lft 5, :name "LCD", :category_id 4} {:rgt 8, :lft 7, :name "PLASMA", :category_id 5} {:rgt 4, :lft 3, :name "TUBE", :category_id 3}], :rgt 9, :lft 2, :name "TELEVISIONS", :category_id 2}]}**

And I want to append some data (products associated with the categories) to all the leaf nodes which are categories of products so that it would look like this:

**{:category_id 1, :name "ELECTRONICS", :lft 1, :rgt 20, :children [{:category_id 6, :name "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS", :lft 10, :rgt 19, :children [{:children [{:rgt 13, :lft 12, :name "FLASH", :category_id 8}], :category_id 7, :name "MP3 PLAYERS", :lft 11, :rgt 14 :products [{:name "SONY MP3 PLAYER"} {:name "SONY MP3 PLAYER 2"}]} {:rgt 18, :lft 17, :name "2 WAY RADIOS", :category_id 10} {:rgt 16, :lft 15, :name "CD PLAYERS", :category_id 9}]} {:children [{:rgt 6, :lft 5, :name "LCD", :category_id 4} {:rgt 8, :lft 7, :name "PLASMA", :category_id 5} {:rgt 4, :lft 3, :name "TUBE", :category_id 3}], :rgt 9, :lft 2, :name "TELEVISIONS", :category_id 2}]}**

*I have added two products to the leaf node "MP3 PLAYERS"*

How can I achieve this using clojure? If not clojure, can I get a solution in any other programming language? like Python etc.?

Comment: Please make a simpler example.  It is hard to tell which part of your question is important and which part is just noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't know where in the hierarchy your category is located you can use this approach:

```
(use 'clojure.walk)

(defn add-to-category
  [catalog cat-id product]
  (postwalk (fn [x]
              (if (and (map? x)
                       (= (:category_id x) cat-id))
                (update-in x [:products] conj product)
                x))
            catalog))
```

Here's your initial map:

```
(def my-catalog {:children
 [{:children
   [{:children [{:name "FLASH", :lft 12, :category_id 8, :rgt 13}],
     :name "MP3 PLAYERS",
     :lft 11,
     :category_id 7,
     :rgt 14}
    {:name "2 WAY RADIOS", :lft 17, :category_id 10, :rgt 18}
    {:name "CD PLAYERS", :lft 15, :category_id 9, :rgt 16}],
   :name "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS",
   :lft 10,
   :category_id 6,
   :rgt 19}
  {:children
   [{:name "LCD", :lft 5, :category_id 4, :rgt 6}
    {:name "PLASMA", :lft 7, :category_id 5, :rgt 8}
    {:name "TUBE", :lft 3, :category_id 3, :rgt 4}],
   :name "TELEVISIONS",
   :lft 2,
   :category_id 2,
   :rgt 9}],
 :name "ELECTRONICS",
 :lft 1,
 :category_id 1,
 :rgt 20}
```

Invoke as:

```
(add-to-category my-catalog 7 {:name "SONY MP3 PLAYER 2"})
```

Comment: Really nice concise answer @Guillermo

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a job for [`update-in`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.core/update-in/).

```
(def categories {:category_id 1, :name "ELECTRONICS", :lft 1, :rgt 20, :children [{:category_id 6, :name "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS", :lft 10, :rgt 19, :children [{:children [{:rgt 13, :lft 12, :name "FLASH", :category_id 8}], :category_id 7, :name "MP3 PLAYERS", :lft 11, :rgt 14} {:rgt 18, :lft 17, :name "2 WAY RADIOS", :category_id 10} {:rgt 16, :lft 15, :name "CD PLAYERS", :category_id 9}]} {:children [{:rgt 6, :lft 5, :name "LCD", :category_id 4} {:rgt 8, :lft 7, :name "PLASMA", :category_id 5} {:rgt 4, :lft 3, :name "TUBE", :category_id 3}], :rgt 9, :lft 2, :name "TELEVISIONS", :category_id 2}]})

(update-in categories [:children 0 :children 0 :products]
                      conj {:name "SONY MP3 PLAYER"} {:name "SONY MP3 PLAYER 2"})

;; Returns a similar giant map. Here with clojure.pprint/pprint formatting:
{:category_id 1,
 :name "ELECTRONICS",
 :lft 1,
 :rgt 20,
 :children
 [{:category_id 6,
   :name "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS",
   :lft 10,
   :rgt 19,
   :children
   [{:products ({:name "SONY MP3 PLAYER 2"} {:name "SONY MP3 PLAYER"}),
     :children [{:rgt 13, :lft 12, :name "FLASH", :category_id 8}],
     :category_id 7,
     :name "MP3 PLAYERS",
     :lft 11,
     :rgt 14}
    {:rgt 18, :lft 17, :name "2 WAY RADIOS", :category_id 10}
    {:rgt 16, :lft 15, :name "CD PLAYERS", :category_id 9}]}
  {:children
   [{:rgt 6, :lft 5, :name "LCD", :category_id 4}
    {:rgt 8, :lft 7, :name "PLASMA", :category_id 5}
    {:rgt 4, :lft 3, :name "TUBE", :category_id 3}],
   :rgt 9,
   :lft 2,
   :name "TELEVISIONS",
   :category_id 2}]}
```

If you specifically need the `:products` to be a vector, you'll want to instead of `conj` use a function which makes a vector if it's passed `nil` as the first argument. `conj` [should work this way starting in 1.7](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#21-transducers), but what I had to hand to test on is older than that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. but I Wanted to append data in a generic way i.e. I have a product vector [{:rgt 6, :lft 5, :name "LCD", :category_id 4, :pro_name "sony bravia"} {:rgt 14, :lft 11, :name "MP3 PLAYERS", :category_id 7, :pro_name "sony mp3 player"}] which stores some products belonging to certain categories. So I want to loop through the map and the product vector and append data.

Comment: Ah. So you need to identify a path to a category with the same `:category_id`, then add the product there? 
Might be able to use `clojure.zip` for that. I might have another look later.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question, eg include the example product vector and update your example accordingly. Please also explain if you only want to match on ```category_id``` and if product categories might be nested. Pls also format the code appropriately.